# Should returning from main() or calling exit() disable thread cancellation?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, language-lawyer

When a thread calls `pthread_exit()`, POSIX requires the cancellation state and type to be set to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE` and `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED` (XSH 2.9.5, under the epigraph *Thread Cancellation Cleanup Handlers*) by the libc implementation.

Threads returning from the function passed as an argument to `pthread_create()` should behave as if they called `pthread_exit()`. But, this is different for the `main()` thread, returning from `main()` should behave as if calling `exit()`.

I can't find any language linking `exit()` to disabling cancellation, or implying the same effects as `pthread_exit()`.

So, should returning from `main()` or calling `exit()` disable thread cancellation?

Comment: Why would it if the thread ceated by the OS loader is not POSIX compliant?

Comment: @MartinJames: huh?? The main thread is a thread (mostly) like any other. `main()` is called from some place in libc. Likewise, libc takes care of threads that return from `main()`, or call `exit()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard functions are not permitted to have effects beyond those specified. `exit` is not specified to have any effect on cancellation state or type, and so on any conforming implementation, it doesn't. You can observe this by installing `atexit` handlers that call `pthread_cancel(pthread_self())` then call any cancellation point. Be aware of the following, however:

> If a function registered by a call to atexit() fails to return, the remaining registered functions shall not be called and the rest of the exit() processing shall not be completed. If exit() is called more than once, the behavior is undefined.

Thus, if an `atexit` handler causes cancellation to be acted upon, `exit` will not complete, but calling it again is undefined behavior. Such a process must then refrain entirely from exiting, use `_exit`, or cause itself to terminate abnormally via a signal.

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly! Do you consider glibc's exit calling tls destructors non-conforming?

Comment: @l3x: sorry, I misread glibc's code. The tls destructors gets only called for the main thread when it exits via longjmp, which it does when it calls `pthread_exit()`, or responds to a cancellation request. Normal return doesn't pass through that code block.

Comment: Oh, thanks for for the clarification. I should have checked myself :D